# signalr Setting displayname from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've created an MVC application, using signalr for a chat page.
I try to pass the displayname for chatting from the viewmodel (string).
When I simply type in a string, everything works fine.
When I pass in the model, it doesn't.
I've debugged and the model is correct (when hitting a breakpoint, I can see the value of the Model is "test" (a string so It must be easy to pass it in the signalr function)

So this works :

```
$('#displayname').val("Test");
```

But this doesn't :

```
$('#displayname').val(Model);
```

On the same view, I've added this to test :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model)
```

And that shows the correct string.

Any ideas on passing that model value into the #displayname parameter?

Comment: `$('#displayname').val(@Model);`

Comment: I've tried that but it makes no difference... when debugging I can see that @Model = "test" but it does not pass in correctly into the function

Comment: try wrapping in quotes to make it string : `$('#displayname').val('@Model');`

Comment: Ok, this helped! Thanks a lot!